# Compiling Vapor as Standalone App on MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, vapor

I would like to compile Vapor with my code as a MacOS app so I can place it on internal server (drag and click to launch it). I would prefer not to have to install Xcode, swift and other development files on the server. I am new to vapor and swift. I have things running when I build it from xCode. Someone else asked if they could embed it in app, there was yes and no response. The yes did not provide any direction as to how to do it. 
Can it be compiled to a standalone OSX App? 
What do I need to do to make it happen? Point me to docs if you know of any. I have compiled apps that are standalone. Just don't know how to do Vapor. 
Thanks

Comment: I'm in the same boat as you.. most people I ask say you can build a command based app and run that. But I hear you, I want to make a macOS standalone app that hosts a webserver when you run it. Hopefully we find an answer!

Comment: @JoeBayLD my answer does what you and the OP ask! I actually do a lot of vapor development on a Raspberry Pi without having vapor installed and (obviously) Xcode. I simply copied a vapor project created on my mac over and did 'swift build'. At some point, I could remove the 'development' bits of swift, but what's the point?

Answer (score 3):

I think, initially at least, you have to install Xcode in order to build a vapor application, just to get the Swift stuff. Having done that, use terminal to change into the vapor project directory and then build and run the application using:

```
vapor update
vapor build
vapor run
```

This will result in an executable being created and run. The actual location depends whether you are compiling for debug or production (set in Config). Assuming you are still at the debug stage, the compiled executable can be run directly by typing:

```
.build/debug/Run
```

from your vapor project's home directory, instead of `vapor run`. It won't run from elsewhere because it uses relative paths to Config, etc.

You could then copy the project tree and executable to another Mac and try installing the Swift runtime libraries, etc. to have it running without Xcode, etc.

Comment: Hi, can we deploy that `.build/release/Run` file on a remote server and it will work without anything else needed?

Comment: `You could then copy the project tree and executable to another Mac and try installing the Swift runtime libraries, etc. to have it running without Xcode, etc.`  This is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Vapor is a web framework, you don't use it like a macOS app, but you need to deploy on your server together with a web server like Nginx.

https://medium.com/@ahmedraad/how-to-deploy-vapor-app-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-run-it-in-production-eef18f7b4f05

Comment: Why couldn't you link all the vapor dependencies to a standalone macOS app and run it?

Comment: Because in order to run you need also a web server like NGiNX, unless you want to use the develop single thread “vapor run”

Comment: i do not understand. I built a vapor app. And i want to compile it and run it all of my end-users who download the app. I do not want to install nginx. I just want the file to be available on their system. But it seems the built Vapor app has many dependencies