# Hot to protect Vapor code from access (any type of access, even physical)?

Tags: macos, security, cloud, hosting, vapor

I am writing backend using Vapor 3 and macOS 10.15 (Mac Mini). The project is ready and working. Problem is how to protect code. I don't want to store code on server unprotected. Question is: how to protect code from anyone who can access to this server (direct, physical access too: someone, who know password can clone it to flash drive)? I heard that it's impossible to build or compile Vapor app in Xcode like iOS application (Product -> Archive) ([Compiling Vapor as Standalone App on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48725561/compiling-vapor-as-standalone-app-on-macos)). If it's possible, please let me know. Code hardening (make code hardly readable) is easy to breach (at least, my version of hardening). Maybe, can I store code (some files with .swift extension) in some cloud storage (Github, Google Drive)? Or, is there any other way to protect code?

Thank you for any help or advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to launch just binary file.

1) Launch `swift build -c release` in your project folder, in the end it will show you the way to compiled binary file.

2) copy compiled binary file (`Run`) to another macOS machine and launch

> The only limitation that on another macOS machine you should have installed all needed libs and packages at the same paths.

Comment: Hi Mike! Thank you for helping me again! I will test it in morning! Look, this method, is it even I needed Swift 5 and Network library? It’s built in in Xcode.

Comment: I'm not sure, so it would be great if you could try and then share your experience :)

Comment: I am receiving errors like: error: 'NWConnection' is only available in macOS 10.14 or newer. But in project I set up minimum version of macOS 10.15

Comment: have you set `platforms: [.macOS(.v10_14)],` in your `Package.swift`?

Comment: and `// swift-tools-version:5.1` at the top of `Package.swift`

Comment: Now swift build -c release worked! but where is the file to launch? Strange, I cannot find it.

Comment: Should be somewhere at `./build/x86_64-.../release/Run`

Comment: Thanks, I think it is working, but I will test on another machine!

Comment: Hi, Thank you again, but I have one last question. 90% of server is working, but when I am trying to open site, I see TemplateKitError.fileNotFound: No file was found at path: /Users/Shared/Resources/Views/index.leaf (TemplateRenderer.swift:78) Do you know how to compile all (even blue folders)?

Comment: As far as I know everything in Vapor3 uses `DirectoryConfig.detect().workDir` to detect work dir. Take a look how it works under the hood, maybe you can configure it somehow

Comment: In Vapor4 you could provide work dir by setting `app.directory.workingDirectory = .init(...)` in `configure.swift`, maybe something like that available in Vapor3

Comment: No, look, I think, you did not get the last question. Folder Resources/Views contains files with extension .leaf (with html code like index.leaf with for default page). But we have to create this folder manually. And later, my build doesn’t have this files. Do you know how to add them?

Comment: These files can't be inside the binary. These assets should be delivered together with binary near it and you should be sure where to put them to make them work cause as you can see your binary looks for them in `/Users/Shared/` for some reason.